# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list while inserting the arraylist

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting this error:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

at here:

```
splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray()); 

sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}'); ",
      ds.InsertPlan("1", splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2],
                    splitItems[3], DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, user, user, "Nil", 1));
```

And the C# code is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;

public partial class Site_Allocation_Plan_Entry : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private void SetInitialRowToGrid()
    {
        // Initialize and Set initial row of Datatable
        var tempDataTable = new DataTable();
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("txtDate1");
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("txtPlace1");
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("txtPlace2");
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("txtDistance");
        tempDataTable.Rows.Add("1", "", "", "");

        // Store that datatable into viewstate
        ViewState["TempTable"] = tempDataTable;

        // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable
        GridView1.DataSource = tempDataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            // Get TempTable from viewstate
            var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];
            DataRow tempRow = null;

            if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Get Grid's TextBox values
                    var dateText =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDate1");
                    var place1Text =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtPlace1");
                    var place2Text =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtPlace2");
                    var distanceText =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDistance");

                    // Create new row and update Row Number
                    tempRow = tempTable.NewRow();

                    tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["txtDate1"] = dateText.Text;
                    tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["txtPlace1"] = place1Text.Text;
                    tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["txtPlace2"] = place2Text.Text;
                    tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["txtDistance"] = distanceText.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }

                // Add data to datatable and viewstate
                tempTable.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                ViewState["TempTable"] = tempTable;

                // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable
                GridView1.DataSource = tempTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }

    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];

            if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var dateText =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDate1");
                    var place1Text =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtPlace1");
                    var place2Text =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtPlace2");
                    var distanceText =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtDistance");

                    dateText.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["txtDate1"].ToString();
                    place1Text.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["txtPlace1"].ToString();
                    place2Text.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["txtPlace2"].ToString();
                    distanceText.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["txtDistance"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.SetInitialRowToGrid();
        }
    }

    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);

        deleteRow(index);
        SetPreviousData();
    }
    private int deleteRow(int index)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            // Get TempTable from viewstate
            var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];


            if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    // Get Grid's TextBox values
                    var dateText =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDate1");
                    var place1Text =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtPlace1");
                    var place2Text =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtPlace2");
                    var distanceText =
                        (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtDistance");                    
                }

                // Add data to datatable and viewstate                
                tempTable.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
                ViewState["TempTable"] = tempTable;

                // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable
                GridView1.DataSource = tempTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks        
        return index;
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtPlace1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtPlace2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtDistance");
                    TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtDate1");

                    //get the values from the TextBoxes
                    //then add it to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values
                    sc.Add(box1.Text + "," + box2.Text + "," + box3.Text + "," + box4.Text);
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                //Call the method for executing inserts
                InsertRecords(sc);
            }
        }
    }
    private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc)
    {
        DS_SiteDataTableAdapters.tbl_planTableAdapter ds;
        ds = new DS_SiteDataTableAdapters.tbl_planTableAdapter();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        string[] splitItems = null;
        string user = Page.User.Identity.Name;
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {


            if (item.Contains(","))
            {
                splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}'); ", ds.InsertPlan("1", splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2], splitItems[3], DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, user, user, "Nil", 1));
            }

        }

        try
        {
            //Display a popup which indicates that the record was successfully inserted
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Script", "alert('Records Successfuly Saved!');", true);

        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);

        }       
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: It looks like the problem is in fetchin items from splitItems araay. Can you check if your splitItems array contains 4 items as you are using splitItems[3]?

Comment: What's the value of `item`?

Comment: @jadavparesh06 Yes I checked in that and I can see 4 items in it..

Comment: @GrantWinney values of item are date, place1, place2, distance.

Comment: Jilu I removed the aspx code to simplify the question for other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sb.AppendFormat format string expects `5` items.

You said ds.InsertPlan() has the following signature, and **the arguments map to InsertPlan()** not **AppendFormat()**. However, InsertPlan() returns a single `int`, so AppendFormat() only has 1 argument, an int value.

```
public virtual int InsertPlan(
       string Plan_ID,                                  <-   "1"
       string Place_1,                                  <- splitItems[0]
       string Place_2,                                  <- splitItems[1]
       string Distance,                                 <- splitItems[2]
       string Date,                                     <- splitItems[3]
       System.Nullable<System.DateTime> Created_Time,   <- DateTime.Now
       System.Nullable<System.DateTime> Updated_Time,   <- DateTime.Now
       string Created_by,                               <- user
       string Updated_By,                               <- user
       string Version_Status,                           <- "Nil"
       System.Nullable<int> p3                          <- 1
     )
```

Your code:

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}'); ",

      ds.InsertPlan("1",            // <-- unless InsertPlan() returns an array, then this
                                    // is only 1 argument to the outer function
                    splitItems[0],
                    splitItems[1],
                    splitItems[2],
                    splitItems[3],
                    DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, user, user, "Nil", 1
                   )
);
```

is like:

```
 sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}'); ",      
                 1);                                // only {0} has a argument
                                                    // {1} ... {4} do not
```

Comment: I checked that and I see 4 items inside the splititem.

Comment: Yeh, I looked at the error wrong. It is about AppendFormat() format string, not the array. I revised.

Comment: ds.InsertPlan is a dataset.. I want those values to be inserted in the database... any alternatives.

Comment: Your code calls 2 functions, sb.AppendFormat and ds.InsertPlan. Perhaps you should be calling one before the other, rather than inside the argument list.

Comment: wait... I'll update my question and enter the whole code for your better understanding.

Comment: What is the return type for ds.InsertPlan()?

Comment: public virtual int InsertPlan(string Plan_ID, string Place_1, string Place_2, string Distance, string Date, global::System.Nullable<global::System.DateTime> Created_Time, global::System.Nullable<global::System.DateTime> Updated_Time, string Created_by, string Updated_By, string Version_Status, global::System.Nullable<int> p3)

Comment: See my edit. Your arguments are all going to InsertPlan, which returns a single integer. Why are you passing a single integer to AppendFormat() ? What are you trying to append?

Comment: I'm really bad at this... Then what supposedly the solution would be?

Comment: I do not know your intent or what you were trying to accomplish. It seems that you've been asked to patch someone else's code and don't have basic C# knowledge? Is that accurate? Do you even have a clear requirement?

Comment: ok as you suggested I've made some changes in my code... And it is:

ds.InsertPlan("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}');", splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2], splitItems[3], DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, user, user, "Nil", 1);

Comment: Thank you so much for your help... appendformat was not required... I understood where I went wrong... Sorry for being a stupid...